# When I have copied cells in excel, it will not allow me to copy/paste from another program

Tags: microsoft-excel, bug

I encountered a weird issue.

When I copy some cells and paste them in excel it works.

Normally, when I then copy some text from a web page or any other program after having copied cells from excel, the cells that were copied are deselected automatically and am able to paste the content into excel.

However, at the moment I have the following behavior:

1. Copy a cell and paste it into some other cell.
2. Go to a website and copy some text
3. Go back to excel and want to paste that text
4. Instead of pasting the copied text from the website it pastes the
   previously copied cells (cells should have been deselected when
   using the copy command, but for some reason, they still seem to be
   copied within excel).
5. However, when pasting it into the notepad, for example, it pastes
   the text from the website. Did anyone encounter this problem before?

The only workaround is to hit ESC every time. But that is not how it normally works. I'm always going back and forward and losing time and my mind because I am not used for it to working like this

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Try pasting in the formula bar

Comment: I think this is the intended behavior. If the cell in `Excel` has the spinny green dashes around it still, than it is on your `Excel` clipboard. When you paste, the `Excel` clipboard overrides the `OS` one. The solution is, as you have mentioned, to press ESC (deselecting the cell) and then paste.

Comment: Do you use Ctrl+C to copy content? Pleae try right-clicking and selecting the Copy  to test

Comment: Hello, thank you for your replies. @blackandorangecat . No it is not normal behaviour. It is supposed to cancel exels copied cells once you copy something from another source.

Comment: @Emily Same behavior with both ways.